# Gnuplot to SVG to LaTeX with formulas

Tags: math-mode, labels, gnuplot, svg

I create plots in gnuplot that I export as svg and include in a LaTeX document.

I would like to type simple LaTeX formula directly in gnuplot that appear properly in the LaTeX document. I noticed that I can do for instance:

```
set output "pic.svg"
set terminal svg
set label "$x$" at 1,1
plot 1/0
```

and the "x" is properly typeset in italics just like in LaTeX math mode. If I try the same with a more sophisticated formula like

```
set label "$\frac{x}{2}$ at 1,1
plot 1/0
```

I run into two problems:

1. The exported svg does not contain backslash nor curly braces. The label appears as "$fracx2".
2. Even if I edit the svg manually to add the braces and backslash back, the resulting pdf after running

> pdflatex --shell-escape document.tex

does not contain the fraction.

How can this be fixed? Ideally I'd stick with the svg-route if possible.

I use \usepackage{svg} , \includesvg and pdflatex to include the svg file.

Comment: Why are you exporting as SVG?  Why don't you just use the `epslatex`, `cairolatex`, or `tikz` terminal?

Comment: @HenriMenke Because that's what I've always been doing. Sometimes I would like to add additional elements to the plot in inkscape which I believe would be difficult to do with the other methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Gnuplot is in `enhanced` mode, which means that strings are checked for formatting characters. You can for example use `set label "x^{2+3}" at 1,3"` resulting in a superscript (`dy="-6.00px"`):

```xml
<tspan font-family="Arial" >x</tspan>
<tspan font-family="Arial"  font-size="9.6" dy="-6.00px">2+3</tspan>
```

However, if you want to use the SVG in LaTeX this does not work as intended, because the `{}` characters are removed and the text ends up in different `<tspan>` tags. The option can be switched off by using `set terminal svg noenhanced`.

The second problem is the backslash `\`, which must be escaped (by preceding it with another backslash) because it is used as a control character (for example the tab character `\t`).

MWE:

```
set terminal svg noenhanced
set label "$\\frac{x}{3}$" at 1,3
set output "pic.svg"
plot x
unset output
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}
\includesvg{pic}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]